# Increase canvas height automatically when adding extra rects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When adding rectangles the canvas height does not scale with it. Changing the canvas height is not an option. I am searching for weeks how to make this possible. My question is when adding multiple rectangles that the canvas height automatically increases with it for example bij 100 pixels so that it shows the complete rectangle and not only a piece of it like now.

Here is how it is now https://jsfiddle.net/5qybcp84/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>IIS7</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/NodeList.js"></script>
        <script src="click.js"></script>
        <script src="date.js"></script>
        <script src='jcanvas.min.js'></script>
        <script src="canvasscript.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Nodes</b>
        <br>
        <div class="scrollbar">
            <div class="content">
                <canvas  id="NodeList" width="200"  style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Display" id="Display">
            <canvas id="NodeDisplay" style="border:2px solid black;" ></canvas>

            <script>
                var ctx = $('#NodeList').get(0).getContext('2d');

                var rects = [[20, 20, 150, 100], [20, 140, 150, 100]];
                for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++) {
                    ctx.fillRect(rects[i][0],
                    rects[i][1],
                    rects[i][2],
                    rects[i][3]);
                }

                $('#NodeList').click(function(e) {
                    var x = e.offsetX,
                    y = e.offsetY;

                    for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++) {
                        if(x > rects[i][0]
                            && x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2]
                            && y > rects[i][1]
                            && y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]) {
                            alert('Rectangle ' + i + ' clicked');
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>

        <div id="canvas-wrap">
        <canvas width="600" height="600" style="border:2px solid black;"></canvas>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div class="een" style="border:2px solid black;" >11111 </div>
        <div class="twee" style="border:2px solid black;" >22222 </div>
        <div class="drie" style="border:2px solid black;" >33333</div>
        <div class="vier" style="border:2px solid black;" >44444 </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

b {
    margin-left: 75px;
}

#container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

a img {
    border:none;
}

.scrollbar{
    width:220px;
    height:1050px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}

.content{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}       

#Display {
    margin-left: 580px;
    float: left;
}    

#NodeDisplay{
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}   

#canvas-wrap { 

    position:fixed;                   
    margin-left: 380px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 435px;
}
#canvas-wrap canvas { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:0
} 

.een{
    height: auto;  
    width: 600px;
}

.twee{
    height: auto;  
    width: 600px;
}

.drie {
    height: auto;  
    width: 600px;

}

.vier{
    height: auto;  
    width: 600px;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the height of the canvas is not an option". Isn't that what you want? You you add a working JSfiddle?

Comment: I dont want to adjust it manually like  <canvas  id="NodeList" width="200" heigth="200" </canvas>. It is not an option to change the height constantly  to like 800 when adding several rectangles or change it back to 200 when deleting rectangles thats why i want to create a script that adds for example 100 pixels in the height when adding rectangles for example. Canvas height is 300 when i add a rectangle the height becomes 400. When i remove it goes back to 300 and so on. I am new to programming as you can see.

Comment: When and How will user end up adding and deleting the rectangles?

Comment: He cant, i will add the rectangles and delete them by code.

Comment: @Script, If you can delete them my code, change the height of the canvas and redraw the elements, When you delete them.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to resize your canvas without stretching your drawings you'll need a draw() method. This draw method will add all object to your canvas. Therefore you'll have to save your object somewhere. You'll need to do this because resizing the canvas clears it. The draw method need to know your current objects and draws them every time you resize the canvas.

You could add some JQuery code:

Everytime you add a rectangle:

```
$('#NodeList').height("+=100");
draw();
```

when you delete a rectangle:

```
$('#NodeList').height("-=100");
draw();
```

In your example that would be for for-loop right now. But the whole loop.

Comment: That'll reset the canvas's contents

Comment: The problem now is that it zooms in, the rectangles also enlarge.